# Firebase Android :Creating atomic field updaters failed, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must be integer type

Tags: android, firebase

My Android app works fine in Debug mode but crashes in Release mode. The problem happens when i try to Sign in using Firebase Auth.App works fine if I set debuggable : true in release build. Log cat provides Atomic field update related errors. Is it because proguard is removing some classes? I have provided code and Logcat below:

```
if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "You are already registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String uid = user.getUid();
                sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(uid, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                sharedPref.edit().clear().commit();

                DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("PB_USERS").document(uid);
                docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document.exists()) {
                                CurrentUser currentUser = document.toObject(CurrentUser.class);
                                ArrayList<String> purchases = currentUser.getPurchases();
                                for (String purchasedTrade : purchases) {
                                    editor.putBoolean(purchasedTrade, false);
                                }
                                editor.apply();


                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();

                            }
```

Error:

```
08-21 17:58:10.571 26027-26054/? E/bfy: Creating atomic field updaters failed
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must be integer type
        at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater$AtomicIntegerFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:52)
        at bfy.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at bfl.a(Unknown Source)
        at bfl.a(Unknown Source)
        at awp.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at arw.a(Unknown Source)
        at ary.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at axh$a.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-21 17:58:10.631 26027-26054/? E/bfx: Creating atomic field updaters failed
    java.lang.ClassCastException
        at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater$AtomicReferenceFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:70)
        at bfx$a.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at bfx.a(Unknown Source)
        at bfx$c.a(Unknown Source)
        at bdt$a.a(Unknown Source)
        at bho.a(Unknown Source)
        at bgw.a(Unknown Source)
        at axs.a(Unknown Source)
        at awm.a(Unknown Source)
        at awy.f(Unknown Source)
        at awy.a(Unknown Source)
        at arl.a(Unknown Source)
        at art.a(Unknown Source)
        at arw.c(Unknown Source)
        at asa.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at axh$a.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-21 17:58:10.639 26027-26054/? E/bil: FieldUpdaterAtomicHelper failed
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must be integer type
        at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater$AtomicIntegerFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:52)
        at bil.a(Unknown Source)
        at bil.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at bgb.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at bho$f.a(Unknown Source)
        at bim.a(Unknown Source)
        at bdt$a.a(Unknown Source)
        at bfy$e.a(Unknown Source)
        at bdt$a.a(Unknown Source)
        at bfx$c.a(Unknown Source)
        at bdt$a.a(Unknown Source)
        at bho.a(Unknown Source)
        at bgw.a(Unknown Source)
        at axs.a(Unknown Source)
        at awm.a(Unknown Source)
        at awy.f(Unknown Source)
        at awy.a(Unknown Source)
        at arl.a(Unknown Source)
        at art.a(Unknown Source)
        at arw.c(Unknown Source)
        at asa.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at axh$a.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am a beginner at Android and Java. Here is the app build.gradle part:

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.permabull.permabull"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my observation, I think the name declaration of the model class(CurrentUser) has changed after using proguard rules so adding a statement to exclude Currentuser.class from proguard will fix the issue. Add the below statement to the progurad-rules.pro file in your project folder

```
-keep class in.permabull.permabull.CurrentUser { *; }
```

Note : If the CurrentUser Class resides in the Path java/in/permabull/permabull/CurrentUser else change according. Cheers :)

Comment: yes.. the app is working fine .. thanks a lot !!!   it would be great if you could tell me how you figured it out :)   As they say - its better to learn to fish than to just get a fish..

Comment: I had also faced the same problem once :) and spent over many days at last I tried this and worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable R8 to resolve this, there's an issue opened with google already https://r8-review.googlesource.com/c/r8/+/26161